# Python pandas split column with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

Hello my dear coders,

I'm new to coding and I've stumbled upon a problem. I want to split a column of a csv file that I have imported via pandas in Python. The column name is `CATEGORY` and contains 1, 2 or 3 values such seperated by a comma (IE: 2343, 3432, 4959) Now I want to split these values into seperate columns named `CATEGORY`, `SUBCATEGORY` and `SUBSUBCATEGORY`.

I have tried this line of code:

```
products_combined[['CATEGORY','SUBCATEGORY', 'SUBSUBCATEGORY']] = products_combined.pop('CATEGORY').str.split(expand=True)
```

But I get this error: `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Would love to hear your feedback <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.CATEGORY.str.split(',').tolist(), columns=['CATEGORY','SUBCATEGORY', 'SUBSUBCATEGORY'])
```

Output:

```
    CATEGORY SUBCATEGORY SUBSUBCATEGORY
0     2343        3432           4959
1     2343        3432           4959
```

Comment: This doesn't give me an error, but also doesn't split the column. It returns the same category value: CATEGORY                                          2399,2400,2655

Comment: Try `split(' ,')` ? Notice the leading whitespace

Comment: That gives me an error: AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns

Comment: Maybe it's something very obvious that I am missing also I'm very new to coding so sorry if I am asking so much

Comment: If I set it to the variable I use for the dataframe then it works, but it only prints out the three new columns and leaves out the rest :O

Comment: You got to `concat` these three columns back to your original column.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be accomplished by creating three new columns and assigning each to a lambda function applied to the 'CATEGORY' column. Like so:

```
products_combined['SUBCATEGORY'] = products_combined['CATEGORY'].apply(lambda original: original[1] if len(original) > 1 else None)
products_combined['SUBSUBCATEGORY'] = products_combined['CATEGORY'].apply(lambda original: original[2] if len(original) > 2 else None)
products_combined['CATEGORY'] = products_combined['CATEGORY'].apply(lambda original: original[0])
```

The `apply()` method called on a series returns a new series that contains the result of running the passed function (in this case, the lambda function) on each row of the original series.

Comment: These return one number values to the categories. Thanks for the help anyway (I got it working)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `split` and then `Series`:

```
(
df[0].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(",")))
     .rename(columns={0:"CATEGORY", 1:"SUBCATEGORY", 2:"SUBSUBCATEGORY"})
)
  CATEGORY SUBCATEGORY SUBSUBCATEGORY
0     2343        3432           4959
1        1         NaN            NaN
2       44          55            NaN
```

Data:

```
d = [["2343,3432,4959"],["1"],["44,55"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```